# Importing external git repository to App Engine Push-to-Deploy

Tags: git, google-app-engine

I'm currently maintaining a external git repository for our appengine project. And now planning to migrate those repo to push-to-deploy. I would like to view the exsisting commits in push-to-deploy after i migrate.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your question, your commits will be listed on the [Google Cloud Console](https://console.developers.google.com) under Release History

Comment: I think It will shows the commit that are made after creating the repo in google. What i need is, to list the commits that are made prev months in my remote server.

Comment: I've managed to import all our SVN history using "git svn" and push it to google. You just need to clone a repository into the folder that the command line tools creates for you